# Cannot click anchor links

Tags: html, css, href

I'm designing this website at the moment for a local business and I've hit a bit of a brick wall that I can't figure out. I have the menu bar that I coded but I can't seem to link the "Contact Us". I figured that maybe it was an issue with the page overlay on the site (because I'm using an `overlay` class to darken the photos that slide) but I changed the `z-index` to make sure that the menubar sat on top of everything. What's even stranger is that all my other links work; meaning that I have links are local to the webpage (ones that scroll to specific places on page) and they all work fine!

I've combed through my code but I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I would assume it would have to be something with the overlay that I'm missing.

Here's the webpage: [RRCycleinc.com](http://rrcycleinc.com)

And here is my code for the whole 'splash' page, if you don't want to go through the trouble of using Google Inspect Element haha.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.menubar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;
}

.menubar ul,
li,
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menubar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menubar.two a {
  color: black;
}

.slider-contain {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.a-slide {
  background-size: cover !important;
}

.slick-slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slick-list,
.slick-track {
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.overlay p {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: auto;
  top: 85%;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.overlay h3 {
  font-size: 55px;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  top: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.overlay h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  top: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Start Menu -->
<div class="menubar">
  <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a style="color:goldenrod;" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Part Catalogs</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Contact / Hours</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Splash Page Slider + Overlay info -->
<div class="slider-contain">
  <div class="overlay">
    <!--<img id="logo" align="right" src="img/logo.png" alt=""> (Logo For Later Use)-->
    <h3>R&R Cycle Inc.</h3>
    <p>Service and Repair for All Makes and Models Since 1979!</p>
    <h2>Call Us Today: 845-336-5910</h2> </div>
  <div class="slick-slider">
    <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-4.jpeg') no-repeat center center"></div>
    <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-2.jpeg') no-repeat center center"></div>
    <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-3.jpeg') no-repeat center center"></div>
    <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-5.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
    <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/sunset-summer-motorcycle.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error comes from Javascript.

Appreciate any feedback on the matter / on my code!

Comment: At a quick look at your site, you are getting jQuery failures for both your "Part Catalogs" and "Contact / Hours" links. The jQuery is stopping the action from taking place

Comment: Ok! So Part Catalogs doesn't exist quite yet, but Contact / Hours does; where are you seeing that I'm getting these failures? I have checked the Chrome console and I don't see any errors?

Comment: Ah! Ok now I see where the error is coming from, a script that I had made for smooth scrolling. I'm going to update the question, maybe you can see why it's throwing the error? I would assume because the way it's coded it's trying to do this on ALL href links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error is coming from this script

Exactly!

You should target only `a` tag selector have `href` start by `#`

This code should work

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: You are a beautiful person! Thank you so much for the updated script code, still learning JS myself. Can you explain to me what you did there? Does Javascript use Regular Expressions? So that href* just basically means that  anything with '#' this script would only apply to?

Comment: It's a jQuery Selector (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). In your case, `a[href*="#"]` or `a[href^="#"]` (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) are working well.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem in http://rrcycleinc.com/js/smoothscroll.js

it not contain if a href attribute have a '#' or not please refer to this :

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Please refer to [this helpful article about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), to see how one should properly answer a question. You can't just throw in a few links.